# auto-complete suggestion for email id using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, email, angularjs-directive

I have an App for sending emails (using angular and bootstrap). And I have some 1000 email-ids in my db.

I want to implement an auto-complete suggestion type of thing in To and CC field( same like Gmail-compose modal box).

If any one has an idea please suggest or suggest some links/tutorials for this.

Comment: what you had tried so far??

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ try this

Comment: @Arpit - I have created a directive for showing To CC Subject Message field. I am sending and saving the mail in DB. Now since basic functionality is working fine, i want to add auto-complete to To and CC field.

Comment: @pankajparkar: thanks buddy.need to implement something like Multiple Select in Chosen

Comment: @shomil You're welocme :), I've added answer with ui-select option.
Mark it if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Angular Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen)**

It working good with angular js

It has good flexibility. Such as it provide better flexibility using "Group By", "Multiple Select", etc.

**[ui-select(ui-select2)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)**

There was lots of bug while i was using ui-select2(older-version).
Recently they had changed there name from ui-select2 to ui-select.
I'm not sure about the latest version of ui-select

I would say Go for Angular Chosen

Comment: do u have any link for doing this with help of pure angularJS.(or rather can it be done in angularJS using ngAutocomplete module  [link] (http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete) )